# Flutter Firestore : How to do something similar to where('fieldName', arrayNotContains: 'something')?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I know that "arrayNotContains" doesn't exist so how can I do this :

I have users. Each users have pictures.
I want to display the pictures of one user to the other users, but only once. So when a user see the picture of someone else, he adds his own ID in an array that is a field of the picture document on Firestore. Something like this :

Image1 {
'owner': 'user1',
'alreadySeen': ['user2']
}

Image2 {
'owner': 'user1',
'alreadySeen': []
}

So here I want to show to user2 the pictures of user1, except the ones that he has already seen (here Image1).
I wanted to do a Firestore query looking like :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Images')
.where('ownerID', isNotEqualTo: currentUserID) // to prevent displaying his own images
.where('alreadySeen', arrayNotContains: currentUserID) // to prevent displaying an image already seen
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not-in` to avoid getting images with `currentUserID` in `alreadySeen` collection.

Here an example from Firebase documentation :

```
citiesRef.where('country', 'not-in', ['USA', 'Japan']);
```

You can see more details here : [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)

The Dart syntax is :

```
citiesRef.where('country', whereNotIn: ['USA', 'Japan'])
```

Comment: Thank you, but is this Dart language?

Comment: I just updated my answer with Dart syntax

Comment: This is not for an array. In this example 'country' is a String field. whereNotIn check if country is not equal to 'USA' or is not equal to 'Japan'.
With this example, what I want would be 'countries': ['USA', 'Japan']. CitiesRef.where('countries', arrayContains: 'Japan')

Comment: Can you please post the solutions you have tried . I belive a good starting point will be to follow the oficial documentation posted on this answer for performing queries on Firestore.